# How to set the price of stop loss at supertrend value at the time of execution

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following code. And I want to set the stop loss at the price of supertrend indicator line at the time when the order was executed.

[image]

My current code trails the supertrend line and sells when the price goes under the line. I want it to sell when it goes below the original line when the order was executed.

my current code looks like this:

```
risk_reward_ratio = 2

if (GoLong and close > supertrend and direction < 0)
    entry_price = close
    stop_loss_price = supertrend
    take_profit_price = entry_price + (entry_price - stop_loss_price) * risk_reward_ratio
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, comment = "BUY")
    strategy.exit("TAKE_PROFIT", "BUY", limit=take_profit_price, stop= supertrend, comment="Take Profit/SL")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code update your stop and limit on eache bar.
If you want to prevent the update once the trade is open you should use :

```
if (GoLong and close > supertrend and direction < 0) and strategy.opentrades == 0
```